# Comparing matching values randomly picked from a list

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to make a slot machine. When testing if the jackpot worked, I found out that even if all three slots are equal to each other, it will only calculate the winnings as if there were only two matching slots.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import random
    a = 'orange'
    b = 'strawberry'
    c = 'pineapple'
    d = 'apple'
    e = 'jackpot'
    slots = [a, b, c, d, e]
    winnings = 0
    
    print('Play slot machine? (yes or no)')
    play = input()
    while play == 'yes':
        print('Please enter a bet amount:')
        bet = float(input())
        slot1 = random.choice(slots)
        slot2 = random.choice(slots)
        slot3 = random.choice(slots)
        print(slot1, " ", slot2, " ", slot3)
        if slot1 == slot2:
            winnings = bet*2
        elif slot2 == slot3:
            winnings = bet*2
        elif slot1 == slot3:
            winnings = bet*2
        elif slot1 == slot2 == slot3:
            winnings = bet*4
        elif all(slot1 and slot2 and slot3) == e:
            winnings = bet*10
        else:
            winnings = 0
        
        print(winnings)
        print('Play slot machine again? (yes or no):')
        play = input()
```

[Winnings should be 250 since all three slots are the jackpot, but winnings are 50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulr3A.png)

I tried making them all `elif`s, but as expected, that didn't work.

Comment: *all(slot1 and slot2 and slot3)* will always equate to True (with your code) and will therefore never be equal to *e*

Comment: Well, if slot1 equals slot2, the rest of your if statement won't be evaluated. And I doubt that the condition "slot1 == slot2 == slot3" will be evaluated as you intend. Just to mark some problems.

Comment: Yup, as @Ronald said, you could put the `slot1 == slot2 == slot3` condition first so that it is not skipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elif` is hurting you how you have this set up.

If, in the case where `s1 == s2 == s3`, the first `if` statement (`s1 == s2`), is executed, and no other elif block is further executed.

If you flip the order of your `elif` chain, you should get the result you expect.

```py
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 'orange'
    b = 'strawberry'
    c = 'pineapple'
    d = 'apple'
    e = 'jackpot'
    slots = [a, b, c, d, e]
    winnings = 0
    
    print('Play slot machine? (yes or no)')
    play = input()
    while play == 'yes':
        print('Please enter a bet amount:')
        bet = float(input())
        slot1 = random.choice(slots)
        slot2 = random.choice(slots)
        slot3 = random.choice(slots)
        print(slot1, " ", slot2, " ", slot3)

        winnings = 0

        if slot1 == slot2 == slot3:
            if slot1 == e: # all are e
              winnings = bet*10
            else:
              winnings = bet*4
        elif slot1 == slot2:
            winnings = bet*2
        elif slot2 == slot3:
            winnings = bet*2
        elif slot1 == slot3:
            winnings = bet*2
        
        print(winnings)
        print('Play slot machine again? (yes or no):')
        play = input()
```